# Fastapi orm_mode to pydantic pasring

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, model, pydantic

I can't get any info on how  the parsing from orm (SQLAlchemy) to Pydantic models works, here is the example:
I have a scheme (model):

```
class DocListOut(BaseModel):
    success: bool
    data: DataBaseOut

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

As you can see, there is another model as a type of "data". This is the `DataBaseOut` scheme:

```
class DataBaseOut(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: str
    # type: str
    tmc_code: str
    Organization: OrganizationOut

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

It also has the OrganizationOut as one the fields. This is it:

```
class OrganizationOut(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: str
    address: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

ORM models:

```
class Document(Base): 
    tablename = 'document' 
    id = Column(String(150), primary_key=True, nullable=False, default=generate_uuid) 
    user_id = Column(String(150), nullable=False) 
    # organization_id = Column(String(150), nullable=True)  
    # available_organization_id = Column(String(150), nullable=True)    
    name = Column(String(150), nullable=True) 
    tmc_code = Column(String(150), nullable=True) 
    row_created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow()) 


class Organization(Base): 
    tablename = 'organization' 
    id = Column(String(150), primary_key=True, nullable=False, default=generate_uuid)
    name = Column(String(450), nullable=True) 
    address = Column(String(500), nullable=True) 
    row_created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
```

So in my route I have to return a `dict` so that my Pydantic model parses it correctly e.g.:

```
@router.get('/document', response_model=schemas.DocListOut)
def get_doc_list(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    data = db.query(Document).first()
    organization = db.query(Organization).first()
    return {'success': True, 'data': data}
```

But, since I am missing the Organization line I have an error, so I tried following:

```
return {'success': True, 'data': data, 'Organization': organizaton}
```

but it doesn't work, same error

```
return {'success': True, 'data': data, 'Organization': {'Organization': organization}}
```

also  doesn't work, same error.

The error is:

```
    pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for DocListOut
    response -> data -> Organization
field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

So how do I pass the Pydantic model a valid `dict` with fields for it to parse, if I have 2-3 layers of models inside other models?

Comment: Whatever is passed under the `'data'` key in the dictionary must have a field `Organization`. What does your `Document` and `Organization` ORM models (the ones you query in the endpoint) look like?

Answer (score 0):

> So what is the way I pass the Pydantic model a valid `dict` with fields for it to parse, if I have 2-3 layers of models inside other models?

This is documented in the (v1) docs on *recursive* or *nested* orm models ([v1](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#recursive-orm-models), [v2](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/concepts/models/#nested-models))

To use nested Pydantic models the orm models also be nested; in the case of the code in the question, the `Document` SQLAlchemy model must have an `organization`<sup>1</sup> attribute to match the structure in the `DatabaseOut` Pydantic model.  In SQLAlchemy this would be implemented by adding a column (`organization_id`) to the `Document` model that references the `id` column of an `Organization`, and by creating a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html)  (`organization`) that creates the link between the two SQLAlchemy models at the Python level<sup>2</sup>.

```py
class Document(Base):
    ...
    organization_id = sa.Column(
        sa.String(150), sa.ForeignKey('organization.id'), nullable=True
    )
    organization = orm.relationship('Organization', uselist=False)
```

Now we can insert some data and demonstrate that Pydantic model can be created succesfully.

```py
with Session.begin() as s:
    org = Organization(name='O', address='Ohio')
    doc = Document(user_id=1, name='A', tmc_code='a', organization=org)
    s.add(doc)

with Session() as s:
    doc = s.scalar(sa.select(Document).limit(1))
    doclist = DocListOut(success=True, data=doc)
    print(f'{doclist=}')
```

outputs

```
doclist=DocListOut(success=True, data=DataBaseOut(id='56d5f564-ab5b-480b-9917-e376a060158f', name='A', tmc_code='a', organization=OrganizationOut(id='e92f3156-468d-4640-85f3-8bfbdfa2ddf0', name='O', address='Ohio')))
```

If a `Document` may not always be associated with an `Organization`, the `DataBaseOut` model can reflect this my making it optional:

```py
# Pydantic v1
from typing import Optional

class DataBaseOut(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: str
    # type: str
    tmc_code: str
    # Set a default of None to make optional.
    organization: Optional[OrganizationOut] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

# Pydantic v2
class DataBaseOut(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

    id: str
    name: str
    # type: str
    tmc_code: str
    organization: OrganizationOut | None = None
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In the question, `DatabaseOut`'s organization field is named `Organization`, but I'm going to use `organization` for consistency with standard Python style and clarity in this answer.

<sup>2</sup> The example is a one-to-one relationship - each doc is associated with a single org.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, but i need all the fields.

Comment: @Wicked I apologise it seems i completely misunderstood the question back in January. No doubt you have worked it out for yourself by now, but I've amended the answer anyway.